# Connection with Wi Fi in android device

Tags: android, wifi, router, android-wifi

I am facing a strange problem with my Android ACE phone. I am able to connect to Wi-Fi and able to browse Google. But unable to connect to my Internal Servers / network. What is the problem? Will it be an issue with the device or is it the problem with router? Same Server is accessible through my IPAD2!!

My client is telling me that they have not blocked my device from accessing their network.. But my device displays "DNS Error"  when i try hitting their server.

So is there any way that I can detect if my user agent or device is blocked by the internal router or network??

Thanks in advance,
Sneha

Comment: What happens when you use the server's ip address instead of relying on the DNS?

Comment: I have not tried this. Let me do that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this is not the place to ask this type of questions. This site is for development/programming related questions. Why don't you use https://android.stackexchange.com/. However I think your issue can be fixed by using custom DNS servers like 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.8.4. Or you could run a port scan on your network and see if they have a DNS server.